# Using fprintf instead of simple printf

Tags: c, linux, operating-system

```
void usage(FILE *stream, int exit_code)
{
    fprintf(stream," Usage %s: options [ inputfile ... ]\n",program_name);
    fprintf(stream,
    "  -h  --help    Display this usage information.\n"
    "  -o  --output    Write output to file.\n"
    "  -v  --verbose    Print verbose messages.\n"  
    );
    exit(exit_code);
}
```

What is the purpose of using FILE *stream instead of just printf, knowing that the purpose is to advice the correct way to use the program.?

I was trying to realize the differences.

Comment: Then the `usage` function can print to any output stream, not only `stdout`. For example `stderr`. Other than that, you have to ask the author of the code.

Comment: I see this pattern being used in [some code](https://github.com/kingtuna/sshpot/blob/master/main.c) where if you ask for help with `-h` it goes to `stdout`, if you made an error in the arguments, it will print the error plus the usage to `stderr`.

Comment: Basically, you're parameterizing your output.  You're then free to hand it any stream you want, including an actual file stream such as a log file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`printf` prints to `stdout`. It can be seen as a convenience wrapper around `fprintf` ...

```c
int fprintf( FILE *restrict stream, const char *restrict format, ... );
```

... which forwards the arguments from `printf` to `fprintf`, but adds `stdout` as the first argument.

The `void usage(FILE *stream, int exit_code)` function uses `fprintf` to be able to write to *any* stream, not just `stdout`.

`fprintf` is often used to print error messages to `stderr` and it's not uncommon for usage instructions to be printed to `stderr` so one use of the function could be

```c
usage(stderr, EXIT_FAILURE);
```

Comment: @Chris Good point. Add note!

Answer (score 1):

Many Unix programs are designed so their standard output can be usefully piped into another program. When the user executes a command, they may redirect its standard output to a file or pipe it to another program. When a program encounters an error in how it was invoked, such as an incorrect use of a command-line switch, you want to tell the user about the error and give them usage information about the program. This information is commonly written to the standard error stream so the user will see it even if standard output is redirected or piped.

(Of course, the user can also redirect or pipe standard error, but then the onus is on them to monitor or review it.)

Some programs have a way of requesting usage information, as with a switch `—help` or `-h`. When this is used, the information is written to the standard output stream, not the standard error stream, because it is a normal request, not an error situation. So the routine that writes the information is parameterized with a pointer to a stream so it can be used in both of these situations.